# Development with NGINX

Tags: java, scala, nginx

I am developing web application using scala. Now it become rather big and I am going to split it to few separated services and glue it with nginx as reverse proxy.

While it was just a scala app it was able to distribute and run it as jar with few config files. But now there is nginx which usually installed as system app. What is the best way to work with nginx in portable manner, to have all app concentrated in one folder?
Should I have *.conf file with host and include reloading nginx in startup script?
Or maybe it will be usefull to have portable nginx binary?

This is for testing and experimental needs only. Production app deployed into server with preconfigured nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used Nginx on Ubuntu quite a lot, I found that it is quite effective to keep .conf files with the project work, along with one or two shell scripts to install and configure them.

You didn't mention your OS, but I can share my experience with Ubuntu if that helps. This is more an OS admin topic than a Scala one per se.

For example, a script might symlink your scripts/myapp.conf file(s) something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
cd $(dirname $0)
TGT=$PWD
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo rm -f myapp.conf
sudo ln -vs $TGT/scripts/myapp.conf myapp.conf
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want to see.

Answer (score 1):

So you have separated services with nginx as reverse proxy in your production. And need to adapt nginx for test environment ? 
If that is one or two machines setup, try not to overenginer setting, but just adapt nginx config manually (and scala server file) as needed (hostname, ports, path etc...). 
Just my 2c.